# How to check if value in database is same with string in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to find out not how to check if exsists, but to check is it same. Here's my code:

```
$user = $_COOKIE["c_user"];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$salt = $_COOKIE["c_salt"];
$chk_salt = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `Salt`='$salt'"));
if ($chk_salt == '0') {
  die("Get out!");
}
else {
  echo "Welcome ".ucwords($user);
}
```

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$host   = 'your_mysql_host';
$dbname = 'your_db_name';
$user   = 'username';
$pass   = 'password';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e)   {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage().'<br>';  
}

$user = $_COOKIE["c_user"];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$salt = $_COOKIE ['c_salt'];
$chckSalt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Salt=:salt");
$chckSalt->bindValue(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$chckSalt->execute ();
if ($chkSalt->rowCount () == 0) {
  die("Get out!");
}
else {
  echo "Welcome ".ucwords($user);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 11

Comment: I forgot that you haven't made a connection with PDO yet. I'll edit it in a few minutes (this was written from my phone)